# Создание шифрованного приватного ключа с паролем и сертификата на его основе средствами C

Tags: c, openssl

Имеется функция по созданию простого сертификата и его приватного ключа. Данная функция взята из сырцов openssl.

```
int mkcert(X509 **x509p, EVP_PKEY **pkeyp, int bits, int serial, int days) {
 char val[250];
 int i;
 X509 *x;
 EVP_PKEY *pk;
 RSA *rsa;
 X509_NAME *name=NULL;

 if ((pkeyp == NULL) || (*pkeyp == NULL)) {
  if ((pk=EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL) {abort(); return(0);}
 }
 else pk= *pkeyp;

 if ((x509p == NULL) || (*x509p == NULL)) {
  if ((x=X509_new()) == NULL) goto err;
 }
 else x= *x509p;

 rsa=RSA_generate_key(bits,RSA_F4,callback,NULL);
 if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pk,rsa)) {abort(); goto err;}
 rsa=NULL;

 X509_set_version(x,2);
 ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x),serial);
 X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x),0);
 X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x),(long)60*60*24*days);
 X509_set_pubkey(x,pk);

 name=X509_get_subject_name(x);
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name,"C",MBSTRING_ASC,"RU",-1,-1,0);
 X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name,"ST",MBSTRING_ASC,"Test",-1,-1,0);
 X509_set_issuer_name(x,name);

 add_ext(x, NID_basic_constraints, "critical,CA:TRUE");
 add_ext(x, NID_key_usage, "critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign");
 add_ext(x, NID_subject_key_identifier, "hash");

 if (!X509_sign(x,pk,EVP_sha1())) goto err;

 *x509p=x;
 *pkeyp=pk;

 return 1;

 err:
  return 0;
}
```

Сертификат и приватный ключ генерируется так

```
int create_cert(void) {
 BIO *bio_err;
 X509 *x509=NULL;
 EVP_PKEY *pkey=NULL;

 CRYPTO_mem_ctrl(CRYPTO_MEM_CHECK_ON);
 bio_err=BIO_new_fp(stderr,BIO_NOCLOSE);
 mkcert(&x509,&pkey,2048,0,1490);

 EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
  ENGINE_cleanup();
 #endif
 CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
 CRYPTO_mem_leaks(bio_err);
 BIO_free(bio_err);
}
```

Не могу найти в документации, где нужно передать параметр, чтобы сгенерировался приватный ключ с паролем и на основе него был создан сертификат.